# Check all / check none checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I' trying to establish user options for checking all and none checkboxes. I use this code:

```
function selectToggle(toggle, form) {
     var myForm = document.forms['cbx'];
     for( var i=0; i < myForm.length; i++ ) { 
          if(toggle) {
               myForm.elements[i].checked = "checked";
          } 
          else {
               myForm.elements[i].checked = "";
          }
     }
}

document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", selectToggle, true);
document.getElementById("none").addEventListener("click", selectToggle, false);
```

Here works only the option `check all` - `check none` doesn't work.

But, if i use instead of event listeners inline javascript like `<a href="javascript:selectToggle(true, 'cbx');">All</a> | <a href="javascript:selectToggle(false, 'cbx');">None</a>` both options work.

How can i force `document.getElementById("none").addEventListener("click", selectToggle, false);` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the [third parameter in `addEventListener` is actually the `useCapture` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax). You are not passing `true` or `false` into the arugment for the function `selectToggle`. To do that, you will need to call it using an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", () => selectToggle(true)));
document.getElementById("none").addEventListener("click", () => selectToggle(false)));
```

I have left out the second argument because it doesn't seem like you're using it in your method at all. However, if the second arugment is to be used as a form identifier, then you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", () => selectToggle(true, 'cbx')));
document.getElementById("none").addEventListener("click", () => selectToggle(false, 'cbx')));
```

---

**Explanation of why your code went wrong:** The reason why in your original code the check all function works, is because when you use `selectToggle` as the callback, like this:

```
document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', selectToggle);
```

...the first argument is actually the `event` object. Since it is an object that is passed to the first argument called `toggle`, `toggle` will always be truthy, hence you will always end up executing the logic inside the `if (toggle) {...}` block.

Comment: do you maybe know, why the last line, with `none`, throws an error `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`?

Comment: @Evgeniy The error tells you that `document.getElementById("none")` returns null. So you need to find out why that element is not being detected in your DOM.